# Switch between list and tree in latex (dynamic typesetting)

Tags: lists, typography, trees

Is it possible to switch between a list and an equivalent tree (both already coded) with a clickable link with latex i.e. toggle between them ?

Does LaTeX allow to typeset dynamically with a clickable link ?

**Edit 1:** The below code shows a list and its equivalent tree.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
%\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
%\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}     
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node  {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node  {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child [missing] {}              
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{itemize}
\item texmf
\begin{itemize}
\item doc
\item fonts
\item source
\item tex
\begin{itemize}
\item generic
\item latex
\item plain
\end{itemize}
\item texdoc
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

What I want is to have a clickable link or button on the page that can toggle between these two (show one at a time). Is this possible in LaTeX?

Comment: Question 1: yes. Question 2: no.

Comment: @cfr can you provide a detailed answer for question 1.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Working Example i.e. code for a small document with the content you describe? It is pretty easy in Beamer, for example.

Comment: Can you please provide a *detailed* [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that codes your list and equivalent tree. It is much easier to help you if we have some working code to start from. Currently we have to guess what you mean by "a list and an equivalent tree", so people are unlikely to offer a solution because it is very likely that they would be wasting their time because these terms are open to misinterpretation.

Comment: @cfr and Andrew Can you check now?

Comment: Does the existing answer do what you need? If not, can you specify your constraints? For example, does it need to be usable in any reasonable PDF viewer, so that Adobe-specific stuff must be avoided? That will limit the options, so it is important to know what your constraints are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can realize such dynamic with Optional Content Groups (OCGs or layers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage[uselayers]{aeb_pro}

\begin{document}

\def\myTree{%
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
%\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
%\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {texmf}
    child { node {doc}}
    child { node {fonts}}
    child { node {source}}
    child { node  {tex}
      child { node {generic}}
      child { node  {latex}}
      child { node {plain}}
    }
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child [missing] {}
    child { node {texdoc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\myItem{%
\begin{itemize}
\item texmf
\begin{itemize}
\item doc
\item fonts
\item source
\item tex
\begin{itemize}
\item generic
\item latex
\item plain
\end{itemize}
\item texdoc
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\pushButton[\CA{Press me to toggle}\autoCenter{n}%
\A{\JS{%
toggleSetThisLayer("myToggleA");
toggleSetThisLayer("myToggleB");
}}]{myBtn}{5cm}{12bp}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\xBld[initState=on]{myToggleA}
\parbox{5cm}{\myTree}
\eBld
&
\xBld[initState=off]{myToggleB}
\parbox{5cm}{\myItem}
\eBld
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The technique is to set one OCG to the initial state to "off" and the other one to "on". With the button you then can toggle between them.

[image]

**Note:** The workflow I was using is: `latex -> dvips -> distiller -> PDF`

Due to implemented JavaScript within the resulting PDF, a JS based PDF-Viewer is needed. Adobe Reader does the best job.

The packages `aeb_pro` and `eforms` are found on CTAN and not part of the TL distribution - however part of the TL contribution.

**EDIT:**

The `aeb_pro` package ships an `aeb_pro.js` file. This file goes to the JavaScripts folder of your Acrobat app.

As I am using Acrobat Pro DC, the JS folder is located at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\Privileged\2015\JavaScripts
```

If the **Privileged** folder is not existing, generate it with the subfolders `2015\JavaScripts`

For older versions the location of the `JavaScripts` folder my be different.

**Workflow:** with command line:

```
latex filename.tex
dvips filename.dvi
```

Then a `filename.ps` in the working folder is generated.

Open this  `*.ps` file with the Distiller and a PDF will be produced.

This process can surely be automized within your favorite editor.

**Note:** Distiller always calls for **ABSOLUTE paths** and not relative.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you let me know how to use-  latex -> dvips -> distiller -> PDF , I am having trouble configuring it.

Comment: @paulplusx: I edited my answer with some hints - hope this will help you

Comment: @paulplusx: JS can make a PDF very dynamic in many more cases than only toggle OCGs, however there is a restriction to the PDF-Viewers as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I was actually thinking whether its possible to integrate JS and TeX before you gave your answer and then you actually gave me the perfect one :). I was looking for that dynamic thing.

Comment: @JürgenG : simpler and more portable with pkg `ocgx2`

Comment: @AlexG : I didn't know your package yet. Indeed very simple and non JS-based.

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler and more **portable** solution with package **`ocgx2`**:

1. any engine: `[(pdf|lua|xe)]latex` --> Distiller not required, `ps2pdf` sufficient for `latex`+`dvips` route
2. no embedded JavaScript  --> better portability (e. g. Evince PDF viewer)
3. all necessary packages in TeXLive (`eforms`, `aeb_pro` not required)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{ocgx2}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myTree{%
  \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
  %\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
  %\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
    two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
    \node {texmf}
      child { node {doc}}
      child { node {fonts}}
      child { node {source}}
      child { node  {tex}
        child { node {generic}}
        child { node  {latex}}
        child { node {plain}}
      }
      child [missing] {}
      child [missing] {}
      child [missing] {}
      child { node {texdoc}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\myItem{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item texmf
  \begin{itemize}
  \item doc
  \item fonts
  \item source
  \item tex
  \begin{itemize}
  \item generic
  \item latex
  \item plain
  \end{itemize}
  \item texdoc
  \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
}

\switchocg{tree list}{\fbox{Press me to toggle}}\\[2ex]

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{ocg}{Tree}{tree}{on}
  \parbox{5cm}{\myTree}
\end{ocg}
&
\begin{ocg}{List}{list}{off}
  \parbox{5cm}{\myItem}
\end{ocg}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```